# I am working on a project to fill data in a pre existing web table

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project where I have to fill data in a pre populated dynamic web table. I am able to find the element with the help of XPath in selenium VBA. I am able to click the element. But Whenever I Try to fill data with sendkey command I get the message "Run time error 0.Element not intractable.

When I try sendKey command with normal id of the element or CSS id then it gets accepted but when I try XPath i get the above message.

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'XYZ')]/following-sibling::td[5]").SendKeys "54"
```

```html
<tr style="background-color:White;height:24px;">
      <td class="gridtext" align="center">
                                                                    <span class="checkboxclass"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdUsers_ctl02_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$chkSelect" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$chkSelect\',\'\')', 0)"></span>
                                                                    
                                                                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$hdnUserId" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdUsers_ctl02_hdnUserId" value="206451744">
                                                                </td><td align="center" style="width:2%;">
                                                                    1
                                                                </td><td class="gridtext" align="center">
                                                                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdUsers_ctl02_lblStudentId" style="display:inline-block;color:#000000;font-family:Calibri;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;width:120px;">091001118051500183</span>
                                                                </td><td class="gridtext" align="center">
                                                                    
                                                                    
                                                                </td><td class="gridtext" align="left" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;">SHIVAKSHI</td><td class="gridtext" align="left" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;">SANJAI KUMAR</td><td class="gridtext" align="left" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;">SANGEETA</td><td class="gridtext" align="left" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;">19/02/2010</td><td class="gridtext" align="center" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;">
                                                                    
                                                                </td><td class="gridtext" align="center">
                                                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$txtNoOfDays" type="text" maxlength="3" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdUsers_ctl02_txtNoOfDays" class="TextBox" onkeypress="return AllowNumeric_Browser(event, false);" onpaste="return false;" style="width:50px;">
                                                                </td><td class="gridtext" align="center">
```

Comment: Can you provide the url? Or the relevant html.

Comment: Thanx for so prompt a response QHarr. I have given the relevant html code if they could be of any use.

Comment: which td field? number of days?

Comment: </td><td class="gridtext" align="center">
                                                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$txtNoOfDays" type="text" maxlength="3" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdUsers_ctl02_txtNoOfDays" class="TextBox" onkeypress="return AllowNumeric_Browser(event, false);" onpaste="return false;" style="width:50px;">
                                                                </td><td class="gridtext" align="center">

Comment: the second last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the child input tag of the td as the td itself is not interactable. So, you need to add `/input` to your current path

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'XYZ')]/following-sibling::td[5]/input").SendKeys "54"
```

Here is a similar example where you select the child `input` of a `td` based on the parent `tr` having a `td` with specific text

```
bot.Get 'https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html'
bot.FindElementByXPath("//tr[contains(td/text(), 'Angelica Ramos')]/td[2]/input").SendKeys "test"
```

Or

```
//td[contains(text(),'Angelica Ramos')]/following-sibling::td[1]/input
```

Comment: Thanx for telling QHarr but I have to select the row based upon the td that contains a particular text. How can I do this with css selector.

Comment: what particular text? You want to use SendKeys so you need to target the input element not tr

Comment: and what is dynamic about the table? Does the id change for that input element?

Comment: What i mean to say that I have pre populated data in tabular form. for example

Comment: What i mean to say that I have pre populated data in tabular form. for example 'John','12/02/1985', [roll no] . here john and 12/02/1985 is pre populated. i have to fill Roll No of John from the excel sheet. and there are a many rows starting with different names.In other form at place of John some other name would be there. so I have to look for the name and then fill the data of that name. That is why I refer the tabel as dynamic.

Comment: FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'Some String')]")  I am using this method. But it rejects to accept the send key command saying that element not interactable.

Comment: Try adding child input to xpath

Comment: Thanx QHarr . Your last code worked. I was very puzzled about this and it really helped . Thanx again.